# 3ds Max python scan objects

Tags: python, 3dsmax

I'm using 3ds Max 2022 and I'm trying to scan my scene, for example I want to get the data about the walls in my scene, by vertices, height, width etc.

I have tried the runtime.objects but the result is only the x, y and z coordinate of the pivot of the wall.

my code:

```
import pymxs
rt = pymxs.runtime
for obj in rt.objects:
  print(obj)
```

is there any way to solve it by any method?

and where can I find a rich documentation for pymxs?

Comment: Dunno about Python, but to my knowledge it's a closer representation of the underlying C++ SDK.  At the API level, objects (e.g. geometry) in 3ds Max are instantiated in the scene graph as INodes.  The pivot transformation is a property of Objects, whereas the transformation is a property of INodes.  Nodes then just reference an Object.  To transform your vertices between object and world space, you must account the instance global transform (from the node) _and_ the pivot transform (from the object).

Answer (score 0):

pymxs is a wrapper around the runtime MAXScript engine, you're supposed to use MAXScript documentation. As for your original question, it all depends on what are the types of your objects, the answer will be different for different sets of objects (AEC walls, extruded lines with non-collapsed stack, editable mesh, editable poly etc) and different expectations (do you want sizes in world space, in local space, are you okay with bounding box sizes, orineted or world-space and so on.

For AEC Walls, the corresponding snippet would be for example:

```
for obj in (obj for obj in rt.objects if rt.isKindOf(obj, rt.Wall)):
    print("{}: height = {}, width = {}".format(obj.name, obj.height, obj.width))
    mesh = rt.snapshotAsMesh(obj)
    for vertex in mesh.vertices:
        print("\tvertex {}: pos = {}".format(vertex.index, vertex.pos))
    rt.delete(mesh)
```

Comment: So for AEC walls how do I get all the properties, for example vertices location, height, width etc.
I'd rather get it without converting to editable Polly, if its possible...

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a code sample for AEC Walls. No new objects are created (the snapshot only creates a TriMesh object without associated node, and disposes of it after all the vertices are queried).